# Comando javac com mais de uma classe empacotada

Tags: java

Tenho 3 classes no pacote `com\scja\exam\planetas`.  Tenho também uma classe com método `main` no pacote `com\scja\exam\teste`, responsável  imprimir o nome dos planetas.

Preciso compilar via linha de comando este código, mas estou com dificuldades.

Seguem as minhas tentativas e as mensagens de erro.:

> **Comando:** `C:\Users\marci_000\Documents\OCA\exercicios>javac -d bin -cp src\com\scja\exam\planetas\*.java;src\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta.java`
>
> **Mensagem de erro:**  `javac: no source files Usage: javac <options> <source files> use -help for a list of possible options`

Tentei também sem a opção `-cp`, porém dá uma mensagem de erro nas linhas onde foram declarados os objetos. Diz que não encontrou:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oi @Marcia, o problema foi resolvido? Se sim não se esqueça de marcar uma resposta como correta (ou ou responder você mesma com a solução que encontrou).

Answer (score 2):

Perceba que você está compilando apenas arquivos JAVA que começam com o nome *planetas* (planetas*.java):

> C:\Users\marci_000\Documents\OCA\exercicios>javac -d bin -cp src\com\scja\exam\planetas*.java;src\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta.java

Acredito que você esqueceu de colocar a "\". Para corrigir, ajusta para:

```
C:\Users\marci_000\Documents\OCA\exercicios>javac -d bin -cp src\com\scja\exam\planetas\*.java;src\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta.java
```

Comment: Valeu galera, problema resolvido. O erro estava no import.Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: @MarciaLima você viu a minha resposta?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer apenas:

```
javac ./com/scja/exam/planetas/*.java ./com/scja/exam/teste/*.java
```

O `./` referencia á raiz do diretório do seu projeto.

Quando queremos compilar mais de um pacote, podemos declarar todos esses pacotes separando-os por espaço.

Ao fazer assim, você compila todas as classes dentro de `com/scja/exam/planetas` e todas as classes dentro de `com/scja/exam/teste`

---

Outra coisa, perceba que no seu print, a primeira mensagem de erro se dá no `import`.

Não é possível importar classes dessa forma.

Ou você importa classe por classe do pacote:

```
import com.scja.exam.planetas.Earth;
```

Ou você importa o pacote inteiro com `*` no final:

```
import com.scja.exam.planetas.*;
```

Nós chamamos isso de `import` explícito e implícito (respectivamente).

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver no windows, crie um arquivo `compila.bat` com o seguinte:

```
cd src
dir /s /B *.java > ../sources.txt
cd ..
javac -d bin @sources.txt
```

E então, basta executar o `compila.bat`.

Se estiver no linux, crie um `compila.sh`:

```
cd src
find -name "*.java" > ../sources.txt
cd ..
javac -d bin @sources.txt
```

E execute esse `compila.sh`.

É importante se notar o seguinte nesses comandos:

- A flag `-cp` serve para você indicar onde estão as classes **já compiladas anteriormente** que serão utilizadas como dependências/bibliotecas. Assim sendo, não é a flag que você quer.
- Este comando funciona ao listar todos os arquivos de códigos-fonte do seu projeto, criar uma lista deles em um arquivo e mandar o `javac` compilar os arquivos que estão na lista.
- É uma abordagem muito mais prática porque você não vai precisar ficar adicionando manualmente os seus arquivos de código-fonte e os pacotes manualmente na linha de comando.
- Funciona para qualquer número de códigos-fonte e de pacotes que existam na sua pasta `src`.