# Interpretando código com classes empacotadas

Tags: java

Tenho 3 classes no pacote `com\scja\exam\planetas`. Tenho também uma classe com método `main` no `pacote com\scja\exam\teste`. O método `main` é responsável por imprimir o nome dos planetas.

Compilei normalmente da seguinte forma:

```
C:\Users\marci_000\Documents\OCA\exercicios>javac -d bin -cp .\src\com\scja\exam\planetas\*.java .\src\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta.java
```

Mas ao executar o comando java, para interpretar, está surgindo a seguinte mensagem:

```
Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal .\bin\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta
```

O comando utilizado para interpretar é o seguinte:

```
C:\Users\marci_000\Documents\OCA\exercicios>java -cp .\bin\com\scja\exam\planetas .\bin\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta
```

Verifiquei as variáveis de ambiente e estão ok. E este erro só ocorre quando estou compilando classes empacotadas. Para classes não empacotadas executa normalmente

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Comando javac com mais de uma classe empacotada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185887/comando-javac-com-mais-de-uma-classe-empacotada)

Comment: Você chegou a ler as outras repostas? Me parece que essa duvida já foi respondida na outra pergunta sua.

Comment: Oi @diegofm, perdão, não tinha visto a pergunta duplicada quando respondi. Ainda que a pergunta agora, do ponto de vista da OP esteja do lado do `java` ao invés do `javac` acabei repetindo muita coisa que foi respondida na outra pergunta. De qualquer forma vou deixar a resposta aqui por enquanto já que lá ela estaria ligeiramente descontextualizada.

Answer (score 2):

## Sobre a compilação

A primeira coisa que você tem que ter em mente é que `src` não faz parte da estrutura de pacotes, ele é apenas o diretório base que contém o código fonte da aplicação.

```
javac -d bin src\com\scja\exam\planetas\*.java src\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta.java
```

O diretório `src` é um excelente candidato para entrar na lista de caminhos em que o `javac` procura código fonte durante a compilação. Essa lista é o *sourcepath*.

A vantagem de usar o *sourcepath* é que, sabendo onde estão os fontes, o `javac` é esperto o suficiente para encontrar e compilar transitivamente todos os arquivos `.java` necessários para fazer `ImprimePlaneta` funcionar. Por exemplo, se `ImprimePlaneta` possui um `import`:

```
import com.scja.exam.planetas.PlanetaEnum;
```

O `javac` sabe encontrar o arquivo `PlanetaEnum.java` no diretório `com\scja\exam\planetas` dentro de algumas das entradas do *sourcepath*:

Ou seja, podemos simplificar a compilação para:

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src src\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta.java
```

Se o *sourcepath* não foi específicado o `javac` usa o valor de *classpath* como *sourcepath*. Logo, também é possível usar a variação abaixo:

```
javac -d bin -cp src src\com\scja\exam\teste\ImprimePlaneta.java
```

Dito isso é importante notar que `-cp` é utilizado para disponibilizar arquivos `.class` para a aplicação. Ainda que um bom projeto por convenção não tenha nenhum arquivo `.class` na pasta `src`, vale a pena deixar a intenção de buscar apenas arquivos de código fonte explícita utilizando  `-sourcepath`.

Terminada a compilação você terá um diretório `bin` com uma estrutura parecida com a seguinte:

```
bin
└───com
    └───scja
        └───exam
            ├───planetas
            │       PlanetaEnum.class
            │
            └───teste
                    ImprimePlaneta.class
```

## Executando a aplicação

Veja que o diretório `bin` é uma contrapartida de `src`. Conforme vimos o `-cp` pode ser utilizado para especificar caminhos em que a aplicação busca por unidades compiladas. Logo a maneira correta de rodar a sua aplicação a partir do diretório `exercicios` é:

```
java -cp bin com.scja.exam.teste.ImprimePlaneta
```

Note que o comando `java` recebe o nome qualificado da classe que deve ser executada. Isso faz sentido pois a classe poderia, por exemplo, estar dentro de um jar.

Como no exemplo do `javac` o comando `java` é inteligente o suficiente para encontrar as classes utilizadas por `ImprimePlaneta` no *classpath*.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda. Consegui executar meu código. Eu estava usando barra, e no caso teria que usar a seguinte estrutura.java -cp bin com.scja.exam.teste.ImprimePlaneta. Valeu pela dica

Comment: Oi Marcia, tudo bem? Fico feliz em ter ajudado, aqui no Stack Overflow sinalizamos boas respostas com votos positivos, a resposta que resolveu seu problema pode ser marcada como correta.